# Moveit2 & ros2_control, Why does it go back in the opposite direction after reaching the target value?

Tags: moveit, ros2-control, ros2-controllers, ros-iron

I am using moveit2 and ros2_control (ros2-iron).

I can move the actuator using interactive-Marker on Rviz, but for some reason, on actual devices, actuators moves back a little after it once reaches the target position. This amount seems to be proportional to the actuator speed.

One of my concerns is whether this phenomenon is an overshoot. If I want to move a joint from 0 to 1, in the case of overshooting, it will eventually reach the target position like 0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.0, but this time it moves like 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8, back a little after reaching the target point. The movement is such that it returns to the position interface value 0.8 at the same time as the command interface value 1.

I have tried several planners, and the same problem occurs no matter which of the multiple actuators I use, so I suspect that there is something wrong with the settings around ros2_control, but I have not found a solution.

My ros2_control_config.yaml is as follows.

```yaml
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 125  # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    A_joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    B_joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

A_joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - A_joint_1
      - A_joint_2
      - A_joint_3
      - A_joint_4
      - A_joint_5
      - A_joint_6
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    open_loop_control: true
    constraints:
      goal_time: 0.0
B_joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - B_joint_1
      - B_joint_2
      - B_joint_3
      - B_joint_4
      - B_joint_5
      - B_joint_6
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    open_loop_control: true
    constraints:
      goal_time: 0.0
```

If you have encountered the same situation or have any insight on this matter, I would appreciate it if you could share it with me.

Comment: Do you have a simulation running or only real hardware?
Try to use it in simulation, e.g., with mock hardware as [described in the demos](https://control.ros.org/iron/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_2/doc/userdoc.html)

Answer (score 1):

The description means overshooting the target position. Here are three troubleshooting tips that might help resolve the issue or give you insight into where the root cause is:

1. **Open loop control**: In the provided configuration, `open_loop_control` is set to true for both A and B joint trajectory controllers. Open-loop control means the controller sends commands to the actuators but does not use feedback to correct any errors or disturbances. This could lead to overshooting the target position, especially if the system dynamics are not accurately calibrated. Consider using closed-loop control to correct the actuator's position.
2. **Control rate and actuator dynamics**: The `update_rate` for the controller manager is set at 125 Hz. Are you sure this rate is appropriate for the dynamics of your actuators? If the actuators are slowly corresponding, it might result in overshooting the target position and then heading back to for correcting. You might need to tune this parameter based on your specific robot and application requirements.
3. **PID controller tunning**: If you're using PID controllers within the low-level trajectory controllers, ensure the gains are appropriately set. Incorrectly tuned PID parameters can cause this overshooting behavior. Also, the `goal_time` constraint is set to 0.0, which is unrealistic for real actuators, leading to aggressive acceleration trying to meet the target instantaneously. Consider increasing it to a realistic value.

While debugging, you can visualize the trajectory joints to see clearly how things change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am in the process of troubleshooting with what you have provided. One of my concerns is whether this phenomenon is an overshoot.
If I want to move a joint from 0 to 1, in the case of overshooting, it will eventually reach the target position like 0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.0, but this time it moves like 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8, and after reaching the target point it goes back a little. The movement is such that it returns to the position interface value 0.8 at the same time as the command interface 1.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks.
It seems that it was caused by an improper setting of the urdf velocity and acceleration.
The actual robot seemed to have a smaller acceleration than the setting.